# How to resolve "try not to call a closure in the expression where it is declared" in macros?

Tags: rust, macros

I have a macro which takes closures and applies a list of values to them. Clippy complains about the code with a warning. [MWE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4087bef00206ea1543317dc2f723d05):

```rust
macro_rules! printit {
    ($range:expr, $($func:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        for x in $range {
            $(println!("{:?} {:?}", x, $func(x));)*
        }
    }};
}

fn main() {
    printit!(
        0..10,
        |x: u64| x.trailing_zeros(),
        |x: u64| x.leading_zeros(),
        |x: u64| x.count_ones()
    );
}
```

Warning:

```
warning: try not to call a closure in the expression where it is declared
  --> src/main.rs:4:40
   |
4  |               $(println!("{:?} {:?}", x, $func(x));)*
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^
...
10 | /     printit!(
11 | |         0..10,
12 | |         |x: u64| x.trailing_zeros(),
13 | |         |x: u64| x.leading_zeros(),
14 | |         |x: u64| x.count_ones()
15 | |     );
   | |_____- in this macro invocation
```

It works. I don't know what the compiler is complaining about.
How do I go about writing this macro to "fix" this warning?

Comment: Just `#[allow(clippy::redundant_closure_call)]` inside the macro

Comment: Changing `$func(x)` to `($func)(x)` eliminates the warning, though it's not clear if that's intended (by clippy) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/1553) with clippy's `redundant_closure_call`-lint that has been around for a while. At the moment, it is probably easiest to simply `allow` this pattern locally.

Clippy is complaining because the macro will expand to

```rust
println!("{:?} {:?}", x, (|x: u64| x.trailing_zeros())(x));
//...
```

where the closure is declared and then immediately called, which is usually unnecessary.

In case of macro-expansion, there are some subtleties around macro hygiene and this lint; but by and large the issue seems to be unresolved due to inattention.